# Оповещение всех подписчиков ActiveMQ

Tags: python, activemq

У меня развёрнут ActiveMQ с поддержкой stomp

```
<transportConnectors>
    <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
</transportConnectors>
```

К ActiveMQ подключаются клиент, который может отправлять сообщения:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from stompy import stomp


try:
    s = stomp.Stomp(amq_ip, amq_port)
    s.connect(username=amq_user, password=amq_pass)  # подключаемся к AMQ
    body = '{"sample_msg": "%s"}' % "for second client"
    message = {
        "destination": "/queue/test_queue",
        "body": body,
        "persistent": "true"
    }
    s.send(message)  # отправляем сообщение
except stomp.ConnectionError:
    print u"Couldn’t connect to the STOMP server."
except stomp.ConnectionTimeoutError:
    print u"Timed-out while establishing connection to the STOMP server."
except stomp.NotConnectedError:
    print u"No longer connected to the STOMP server."
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

и несколько клиентов, которые могут принять сообщение:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from stompy import stomp
import json


s = stomp.Stomp(amq_ip, amq_port)

try:
    s.connect(username=amq_user, password=amq_pass)
    s.subscribe({'destination': '/queue/%s' % amq_queue, 'ack': 'client'})
except Exception as e:
    print "ActiveMQ error\n %s" % e

while True:
    try:
        frame = s.receive_frame()
        body = json.loads(frame.body)

        # это сообщение для меня?
        if body["sample_msg"] == "for first client":
            print "Its for me. I receive it"
            # Это сообщение для меня. Я его приму и обработаю
            s.ack(frame)
        else:
            # Это сообщение предназначено для кого-то другого и мне не подходит
            print "Its not for me"
    except Exception as e:
        print e
```

В текущей конфигурации сообщение из AMQ забирает только один клиент. Но не факт, что именно этот клиент должен обрабатывать это сообщение.

Как мне сделать широковещательную рассылку сообщения? Или может есть возможность идентифицировать подписанных на очередь клиентов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для оповещения всех подписчиков необходимо использовать `/topic/test_topic` вместо очереди `/queue/test_topic`

Ответ получен на [англоязычном сегменте so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020899/how-to-notify-all-subscribers-of-activemq/41021165)